# Build Failed with Cordova FCM + Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugin-fcm

i am facing the build issue while creating build. But if i remove the FCM plugin it is working fine. Did few code change in current build. with FCM previous build worked well. please help to fix.

```
 :transformClassesWithDexForDebugDex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
   Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
   This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 
 8 
    or above.
   If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add
   targetCompatibility = '1.7'
   sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
   to that submodule's build.gradle file.
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I downgraded the cordova version to 7.1 from 8